# Using temporal data from CSV file for fixed shapes to create animation

Tags: qgis

I have this excel file (pic attached) and I have a shapefile of the states of India.

How do I use this excel file and create an animation in QGIS on the data in the column named `Status` i.e. `Column E`?

Comment: We don't see your image, you can use the "edit" button.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the excel file in excel and export it as a CSV (technically QGIS can import an excel file but it often has issues, so CSV is a much safer format).
2. [Join](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#joins-properties) the shapefile and the CSV.
3. Use the Time Manager plugin to create the animation.